# 'couldn't find "libopvpnutil.so"' OpenVPN android Library

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

**Hello Developers**

I'm trying to integrate OpenVPN Library in an existing android app. When I'm trying to connect to a profile the following error is showing,

***couldn't find "libopvpnutil.so"***

Please help me to solve this problem.